# getpwnam on Ubuntu behaves differently if compiled in 32-bit

Tags: c, ubuntu, ldap, getpwnam

I'm setting up a ZABBIX agent (written in C) on a couple of Ubuntu 64-bit servers.  I usually compile everything in 32-bit unless I specifically need 64-bit (such as database servers.)  The servers in question will be hosting virtual servers and have 8GB RAM, hence why I've kept them 64-bit.

If the ZABBIX agent starts as root, it tries to drop-down to the permission level of the zabbix user, which it looks up using the C getpwnam() function.

On a pure 32-bit system, this function behaves.  However, when compiled in 32-bit on a 64-bit system, getpwnam() returns NULL when a user does exist.  If compiled in 64-bit on a 64-bit system it works fine.

I've mocked up a little application that proves this, but I'm hopeful it's more my setup than a bug in GCC or the STL - the zabbix user is in an LDAP directory.

Firstly here's the output of this program:

```
root@sydney:/tmp# getent passwd|grep zabbix
zabbix:x:1500:1500:Zabbix Service:/home/zabbix:/bin/bash

root@sydney:/tmp# gcc main.c
root@sydney:/tmp# ./a.out
User zabbix exists with UID 1500.

root@sydney:/tmp# gcc -m32 main.c
root@sydney:/tmp# ./a.out
User zabbix does not exist.
```

Here's the code for my little program which I've adapted using the ZABBIX agent source code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main(int num_args, char** args)
{
        struct passwd           *pwd;
        char                    user[7] = "zabbix";

        pwd = getpwnam(user);
        if (NULL == pwd)
        {
                fprintf(stdout, "User %s does not exist.\r\n", user);
                return 1;
        }
        else
        {
                fprintf(stdout, "User %s exists with UID %d.\r\n", user, pwd->pw_uid);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

If this turns out to be an issue with my setup I'll gladly ask on serverfault.com, but I thought as it centres around the getpwnam() function it was more programming-related.  I've also Google'd but not found anything useful which is why I'm inclined to think it's my setup.

Comment: Why do you need it compiled in 32-bit on 64-bit machines?

Comment: `getent passwd zabbix` would have sufficed, no `grep` necessary ;-)

Comment: @Nikolai - because the servers are hosting virtual machines, I need to use as little memory footprint in the host OS as possible, and the ZABBIX agent is a tiny application.  @ephemient - didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to support non-traditional name lookups (i.e. LDAP instead of just `/etc/{passwd,shadow}`), libc uses the [Name Service Switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch).  Some methods are not built into libc and must be loaded separately: `/lib/libnss_ldap.so.2`, for example.  This is actually [quite problematic](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/no_static_linking.html) when statically linking – you aren't doing that, are you?

Obviously the same module cannot be used for both 64-bit and 32-bit.  Ubuntu Karmic ships `/lib32/libnss_ldap.so.2` in package `ia32-libs` – is this installed?

Comment: Not statically linking that I'm aware (using ZABBIX's configure script.)  Installing ia32-libs worked, thanks.  I thought 64-bit systems automatically included support for 32-bit apps.

Answer (score 0):

Both multilib, and ia32 libs must be installed.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs gcc-multilib
```

Similar answer here: [gcc cannot find bits/predefs.h on i686](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591629/gcc-cannot-find-bits-predefs-h-on-i686)