# RUN command in dockerfile produces different result than manually running same commands inside container

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-12.04

I am creating a Ubuntu 12.04 docker image that has gcc 4.8.5. I am getting gcc 4.8.5 source and building it myself. This container will be running on a Ubuntu 18.04 host.

Referencing the code at the bottom, if I don't put this in the dockerfile and run the same commands after starting the container, the build works fine, however if I use RUN instead in the dockerfile, I get the following build error

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
             from ../../../gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:87,
             from ../../../gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/libgcc2.c:27:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such 
file or directory
#include <bits/predefs.h>
                      ^
```

The problem seems to stem from the ./gcc-4.8.5/configure call.
When run inside the container i get:

```
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
```

When put in the dockerfile i get:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Can someone fill in my understanding of the RUN in dockerfiles because i feel like i am missing something about how its working. I was under the impression that those commands would run in the previous layer? But it seems like they are running on my host.

```
## Get gcc 4.8.5 and build it
RUN wget ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz \
&& tar xzf gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz && \
cd gcc-4.8.5 && \
./contrib/download_prerequisites && \
cd .. && mkdir gccbuild && cd gccbuild && \
../gcc-4.8.5/configure \
--prefix="/opt/gcc" \
--enable-shared --with-system-zlib --enable-threads=posix \
--enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-checking --enable-gnu-indirect-function \
--enable-languages="c,c++" --disable-bootstrap \
&& make all && make install
```

EDIT:

```
docker build -t 12.04_builder - < dockerfile
docker run -i -t 12.04_builder
```

Complete dockerfile:

```
FROM jnickborys/i386-ubuntu:12.04

RUN apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get install -y \ 
      wget \
      build-essential \
      libssl-dev \
      git \
      asciidoc \
      libpulse-dev \
      libasound2-dev \
      libpcsclite-dev 

## Get latest cmake that has a 32-bit version
RUN wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.6.3/cmake-3.6.3-Linux-i386.sh && \ 
    chmod +x cmake-3.6.3-Linux-i386.sh && \ 
    ./cmake-3.6.3-Linux-i386.sh --skip-license --prefix=/usr

## Get gcc 4.8.5 and build it
RUN wget ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz \
    && tar xzf gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz && \
    cd gcc-4.8.5 && \
    ./contrib/download_prerequisites && \
    cd .. && mkdir gccbuild && cd gccbuild && \
    ../gcc-4.8.5/configure \
    --prefix="/opt/gcc" \
    --enable-shared --with-system-zlib --enable-threads=posix \
    --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-checking --enable-gnu-indirect-function \
    --enable-languages="c,c++" --disable-bootstrap 
    && make all && make install
```

Comment: Can you share full `Dockerfile` and the way you start the container together with command line inside container

Comment: I have added the complete file with how i am building it and running it

Comment: Not sure if this will help. But maybe try installing `gcc-multilib` as described here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12615029/1421222

Comment: Did try that, it doesn't work. If that was the case then running the commands inside the container would fail too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, a little bit of background: the platform detection script which runs during the build uses `uname(1)` utility (thus `uname(2)` system call) to identify the hardware it runs on:

```
root@6e4b69adfd4c:/gcc-4.8.5# grep 'uname -m' config.guess 
UNAME_MACHINE=`(uname -m) 2>/dev/null` || UNAME_MACHINE=unknown
```

On your 64-bit machine `uname -m` returns `x86_64`. However, there is a system call which allows overriding this result: `personality(2)`. When the process calls `personality(2)`, it and its subsequent forks (children) start seeing the fake results when calling `uname(2)`. So, there is the possibility to ask the kernel to provide the fake hardware information in `uname(2)`.

The base image you use (`jnickborys/i386-ubuntu:12.04`) contains the 32-bit binaries and defines the entrypoint `/usr/bin/linux32`, which calls `personality(PER_LINUX32)` to ask the kernel to pretend that it runs on 32-bit hardware and to return `i686` in `uname(2)` (this may be checked using `docker inspect` and `strace` respectively). This makes possible to pretend that the containerized process runs in 32-bit environment.

What is the difference between executing the build in `RUN` directive and manually in the container?

When you execute the build in `RUN`, Docker does not use the entrypoint to run the commands. It uses what is specified in the `SHELL` directive instead (default is `/bin/sh -c`). This means that the personality of the shell running the build is not altered, and it (and the child processes) sees the real hardware information - `x86_64`, thus, you get `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` build system type in 32-bit environment and the build fails.

When you run the build manually in the container (e.g. after starting it using `docker run -it jnickborys/i386-ubuntu:12.04` and then performing the same steps as in the Dockerfile), the entrypoint is called, thus, the personality is altered, and the kernel starts reporting that it runs on 32-bit hardware (`i686`), so you get `i686-pc-linux-gnu` build system type, and the build runs correctly.

How to fix this? Depends on what do you want. If your goal is to build gcc for 64-bit environment, just use the 64-bit base image. If you want to build for 32-bit environment, one of your options is to alter the `SHELL` being used for `RUN`s before these `RUN`s:

```
SHELL ["/usr/bin/linux32", "/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

This will make Docker execute `RUN`s with altered personality, so, the build system type will be detected correctly (`i686-pc-linux-gnu`) and the build will succeed. If required, you may change the `SHELL` back to `/bin/sh -c` after the build.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of how things are working. Exactly what i was looking for.